# Summarizing and displaying data based on user inputs in Shiny

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I am currently reading [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/) by Hadley Wickham and exploring the processes behind building dashboards for reporting purposes.

My first question was solved by [jpdugo17](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11168766/jpdugo17), <strike>how can I use date range and periods to filter and group_by a dataframe in the server? I Have tried placing the `inputId = "daterange_Revenue"` inside filter with brackets but that has not given me any results.</strike> In regards to the group by, I have managed to group the information using the examples from [Chapter 12](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#action-tidy) but I am unable to get my graphs to display linear time. I tried using `scale_x_continuous(date_labels = "%b %Y")` but it yields errors and stops the app from working. My goal is to show Daily, Monthly or Yearly points depending on user date range inputs. Any suggestions?

Code in Progress V2:

```
Transactions <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1577836800, 1577836800, 1580515200, 
                                                  1580515200, 1583020800, 1583020800, 1585699200, 1585699200, 1588291200, 
                                                  1588291200, 1590969600, 1590969600, 1593561600, 1593561600, 1596240000, 
                                                  1596240000, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1601510400, 1601510400, 1604188800, 
                                                  1604188800, 1606780800, 1606780800, 1609459200, 1609459200, 1612137600, 
                                                  1612137600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                               total_price = c(2919, 2448, 2308, 1917, 2842, 1496, 2225, 
                                               1501, 1135, 1786, 2129, 1739, 1414, 1810, 2091, 2596, 1191, 
                                               2217, 1084, 2819, 2435, 2418, 1992, 2116, 2312, 1037, 2355, 
                                               2990)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                         "data.frame"))
ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput(
    inputId = "daterange_Revenue",
    label = "Choose a date range:",
    start = min(Transactions$Date),
    end = max(Transactions$Date)
  ),
  # User Input Select
  selectInput(
    inputId = "period_Revenue",
    label = "Choose time span:",
    choices = list("Daily" = "Day", "Monthly" = "Month", "Yearly" = "Year"),
    selected = 1
  ),
  #User Select Radio Botton
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "geom_Revenue", 
    label = "Plot type:",
    choices = c("Bar", "Line"),
    selected = "Bar"
  ),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = "graph_revenue")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  

  # Prepare Data Set
  Transactions_reactive <- reactive({
    Transactions %>%
      mutate(Day= day(Date), 
             Month = month(Date, label = FALSE), 
             MonthName = month(Date, label = TRUE),
             Year = year(Date)) %>%
      filter(Date >= input$daterange_Revenue[1] & Date <= input$daterange_Revenue[2])
  })

  #Time Span
  period_reactive <- reactive({
    if (input$period_Revenue == "Day") {
      Transactions_reactive() %>%
        group_by(Year,Month,Day) %>% #input$period_Revenue
        summarise(revenue = sum(total_price))
    } else if (input$period_Revenue == "Month") {
      Transactions_reactive() %>%
        group_by(Year,Month) %>% #input$period_Revenue
        summarise(revenue = sum(total_price))    
      } else if (input$period_Revenue == "Year"){
        Transactions_reactive() %>%
          group_by(Year) %>% #input$period_Revenue
          summarise(revenue = sum(total_price))
    }
    })
  
  # GEOM SELECTION
  plot_geom <- reactive({
    switch(input$geom_Revenue,
           Bar = geom_col(),
           Line = geom_line()
    )
  })
  
  output$graph_revenue <- renderPlot({
    period_reactive() %>%
      ggplot(aes(.data[[input$period_Revenue]], revenue)) +
      #How to reference geom using user input
      plot_geom() +
      labs(title = str_c("Revenue obtained between ", format(input$daterange_Revenue[1], "%d/%m/%y"), " and ", format(input$daterange_Revenue[2], "%d/%m/%y")),
           caption = str_c("Generated on: ", format(Sys.Date(), "%d/%m/%y")),
           x = "Period",
           y = "Dolar Amount in AUD") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      #scale_x_continuous(date_labels = "%b %Y") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
    
  })
  
  observe({
    print(names(Transactions_reactive()))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `input$` before the input name. I made some minor changes to the app, for example, the string that went to the title needed to be pasted together.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

Transactions <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1577836800, 1577836800, 1580515200, 
                                                  1580515200, 1583020800, 1583020800, 1585699200, 1585699200, 1588291200, 
                                                  1588291200, 1590969600, 1590969600, 1593561600, 1593561600, 1596240000, 
                                                  1596240000, 1598918400, 1598918400, 1601510400, 1601510400, 1604188800, 
                                                  1604188800, 1606780800, 1606780800, 1609459200, 1609459200, 1612137600, 
                                                  1612137600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                               total_price = c(2919, 2448, 2308, 1917, 2842, 1496, 2225, 
                                               1501, 1135, 1786, 2129, 1739, 1414, 1810, 2091, 2596, 1191, 
                                               2217, 1084, 2819, 2435, 2418, 1992, 2116, 2312, 1037, 2355, 
                                               2990)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                          "data.frame"))



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Test"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput(inputId = "daterange_Revenue", 
                     label = "Choose a date range:",
                     start = min(Transactions$Date),
                     end = max(Transactions$Date)),
      selectInput(inputId = "period_Revenue",
                  label = "Choose time span:",
                  choices = list("Daily" = "daily", "Monthly" = "monthly", "Yearly" = "yearly"), 
                  selected = 1),
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel(
        
        tabPanel("Graph", 
                 plotOutput(outputId = "graph_revenue")),
        
        tabPanel("Table", 
                 tableOutput(outputId = "table_revenue"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  

  #Prepare Data Set
  Transactions_reactive <- reactive({Transactions %>%
    
    filter(Date >= input$daterange_Revenue[1] & Date <= input$daterange_Revenue[2]) %>%
    
    group_by(input$period_Revenue) %>%
    summarise(revenue = sum(total_price))
  })
  
  
  output$graph_revenue <- renderPlot({
    Transactions_reactive() %>%
    ggplot(aes(input$period_Revenue, revenue)) +
      geom_col() +
      ggtitle(label = str_c("Revenue obtained between ", format(input$daterange_Revenue[1],'%d/%m/%y'), " and ", format(input$daterange_Revenue[2],'%d/%m/%y')),
           subtitle  = str_c("Generated on: ", format(Sys.Date(), '%d/%m/%y')))
    })


    output$table_revenue <- function(){
      Transactions_reactive() %>%
        #rename("Period" = period_Revenue, "Revenue" = revenue) %>%
        knitr::kable(caption = str_c("Revenue obtained between ", format(input$daterange_Revenue[1],'%d/%m/%y'), " and ", format(input$daterange_Revenue[2],'%d/%m/%y'))) %>%
              kableExtra::kable_classic(full_width = T, html_font = "Cambria")
    }
    
    observe({
      print(names(Transactions_reactive()))
    })

  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't realize the input$ was needed if the variable was specified. To get the Select input working in the group by, I extracted the Day, Month, Year in the preparing the Data Set code chunk (updated above) and named those columns the same way I called the choices but the plotted output does not change, what could be the problem here? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, ended up using  group_by(Period= floor_date(Date, "period")) and that solved the issue of grouping, thanks for your input!